# DragDropHandlers IShellExtInit::Initialize and NETHOOD UNC paths

Tags: windows, winapi, explorer, windows-explorer, windows-shell

I have a shell extension registered under HKCR\Folder\shellex\DragDropHandlers and I need to call GetVolumePathName()+GetVolumeInformation() on the target folder (PIDL passed to you in [IShellExtInit::Initialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

The problem is that when something is dropped on a "Nethood shortcut" (`My Network Places\sharename`) the PIDL passed to Initialize refers to the Nethood shortcut and not the UNC path! (Calling SHGetPathFromIDList on the PIDL returns `"%USERPROFILE%\NetHood\SHARE on MACHINE"` and not `"\\MACHINE\SHARE"` like you would expect)

I also tried creating a IShellItem of the PIDL and calling IShellItem::GetDisplayName with various SIGDN values but none of them return the UNC path.

How can I get the UNC path from this PIDL?

Comment: AFAIR those are folders which contains a 'desktop.ini' and a 'target.lnk'. You should resolve the 'target.lnk' in the folder.

Comment: Yes I know they contain those files, but resolving them on my own can't be the correct way to do this. target.lnk is an implementation detail of the IShellFolder that handles the nethood folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// error checking omitted
IShellFolder* pFolder = NULL;
LPCITEMIDLIST pidlChild = NULL;
hr = SHBindToParent(pidl, IID_IShellFolder, (void**)&pFolder, &pidlChild);
SFGAOF Attributes = SFGAO_LINK;
hr = pFolder->GetAttributesOf(1, &pidlChild, &Attributes);
if(Attributes & SFGAO_LINK)
{
    // item is a link; get it's target path
    IShellLink* pLink = NULL;
    hr = pFolder->GetUIObjectOf(NULL, 1, &pidlChild, IID_IShellLink, NULL, (void**)&pLink);
    TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
    hr = pLink->GetPath(szPath, MAX_PATH, NULL, 0); // szPath now contains path of UNC share
    pLink->Release();
    pLink = NULL;
}
pFolder->Release();
pFolder = NULL;
```

Comment: Edit: GetAttributesOf's SFGAOF parameter is IN and OUT, I guess SFGAO_LINK is a cached flag and you got lucky ;)

Comment: I suspect there is more than one way to skin this cat, possibly by using IPersistFolder3::GetFolderTargetInfo() or SHGetDataFromIDList(SHGDFIL_NETRESOURCE) but I will accept this as the answer unless someone comes up with a better (and/or documented) way...

Comment: Nice catch; probably returns all attributes if you pass 0, though this isn't documented.  As for other methods, I would stick with this as it is more generic.